# How do I make IO ports which by made of generate function in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to make a simple DUT witch is including so many instances to implement to FPGA.

How do I make I/O ports which by made to instantiated DUT?

AS you can see the below code, there are TEST DUT, and I want to make 84 input_data I/O in TOP module.

If I use a way of using the below, top's input_data is connected to all of instances's input_data.

But I want to make each 84's I/O ports and connect them.

But I don't know how to do that.

Would you please help me what am I supposed to do ?

```
module top(

   input_data0,
   input_data1,
   input_data2,
   //...
   input_data83,

// TODO make I/O ports
);
// to declare reg/wire signals.

  input  signed [49:0] input_data0;
  input  signed [49:0] input_data1;
  input  signed [49:0] input_data2;
   //....
  input  signed [49:0] input_data83;


  // I'd like to connect between input_data0~input_data83 and u_test's 83 input_data 



genvar i;
generate

    for (i=0; i<84; i=i+1) begin : amp
    TEST u_test (
        .in_input       (   input_data  )
    );  
end 



endgenerate

endmodule
```

Comment: Two dimensional ports are not allowed in Verilog. If you are using SV, then you can simply define array of ports like `[49:0] input_data[84];` and connect them using iterator value. But in Verilog you can write a script/use some editor functionality that creates a file with all the repetitive lines for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Verilog. In SystemVerilog, you would make your input_data port an array.

The best you can do in Verilog, is create a very big vector, and take a slice of it to connect to each TEST module

```
module top( input wire [(84*50)-1:0] input_data,

// TODO make I/O ports
);

genvar i;
for (i=0; i<84; i=i+1) begin : amp
    TEST u_test (
        .in_input       (   input_data[i*50 +:50] )
    );  
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks but  I'm not using systemverilog, Is there any closer way to implement them?

Comment: My answer is in Verilog-2001

Comment: oh. Thanks. I'll do this. nice!!

Comment: where is I come from?

Comment: Typo. Should be `i `